# I need the thread function to print the random number for every 2 seconds without stopping the actual program

Tags: c++, multithreading, while-loop, do-while

```
vector < component * > v;
void add(int type, int id, string name) {
    //creating object and pushing into the vector
}

void display()
//display the values
void thred1(int id) {
    bool err = false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (id == v[i] - > id) {
            cout << "element found " << v[i] - > id << " -- " << v[i] - > name << endl;
            v[i] - > Read();
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
            err = true;
            break;

        } else
            cout << "NOT FOUND" << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    int choose;
    int type;
    int id;
    string name;
    int sec;
    do {
        cout << "1.ADD A COMPONENT" << endl;
        cout << "2.DISPLAY A COMPONENT" << endl;
        cout << "3.START MONITORING" << endl;
        cout << "4.STOP MONITORING" << endl;
        cout << "5.QUIT" << endl;
        cin >> choose;
        switch (choose) {
        case 1:
            //adding component  
        case 2:
            {
                display();
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            {
                int id;
                cout << "ID to be monitored" << endl;;
                cin >> id;
                thread the1(thred1, id);
                the1.join();
                break;
            }
        case 4:
            {
                cout << "monitoring stopped" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (choose == 5)
            break;
    } while (true);
}
```

When thread is executed, it prints the random number just once, I need to print it every 2 sec. For example: When monitoring option is selected, the values has to be printed till stop monitoring is pressed.
Meanwhile I need to add the component or display it while it prints.

Comment: Put `the1.join();` under `case 4:` (possibly with checking of joinability). Anyway, note that `std::vector` **is not thread-safe**.

Comment: Also, the code in `thred1()` should be in a loop (`while (true) { }`). You'll need some way to tell it to end the loop.

Comment: Then it will be "not in the scope" @DanielLangr

Comment: @inihsrah Sure, you need to declare it outside of `case 3:`.

Comment: Side note: brackets `{ }` are not required in the `case` blocks (unless you are declaring a local variable).

Comment: Thanks..And how can I simultaneously call the main function to add other components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, your code doesn't fully make sense, but multithreading can be confusing when you first start out.

You do this:

```
    case 3:
        {
            int id;
            cout << "ID to be monitored" << endl;;
            cin >> id;
            thread the1(thred1, id);
            the1.join();
            break;
        }
```

What this code does is collect your ID, create the thread, and then waits for the thread to complete. Maybe that's what you want, but I don't understand why you would create a thread then immediately have the main thread block until the first thread is done.

But that's what the1.join() does -- it blocks the main execution thread until the worker thread is finished. Is this what you want?

Next, your worker thread is quite simple. It searches your vector, pausing 1 second for each loop. It does NOT do any sort of run-forever. It just runs through your vector, searching for the value you passed it. Is that what you want?

Without getting into mutex locking and conditional variables (which you're going to need to learn if you're going to write multithreaded programming), I would change this a little.

Keeping your code mainly intact...

In the main thread, I would declare a variable.

```
thread * myThread = nullptr;
```

I would also declare a global variable called "stopThread":

```
bool stopThread = false;
```

For case 3, I would rewrite it as:

case 3:
        {
            int id;
            cout << "ID to be monitored" << endl;;
            cin >> id;
            // This kills the old thread in case they do option 3 twice.
            if (myThread != nullptr) {
                stopThread = true;
                myThread->join();
                delete myThread;
            }
            stopThread = false;
            myThread = new thread(thred1, id);
            break;
        }

For case 4:

```
case 4:
   if (myThread != nullptr) {
       stopThread = true;
       myThread.join();
       delete myThread;
       myThread = nullptr;
       cout << "monitoring stopped" << endl;
    }
    break;
```

Then you in your thread method:

```
void thred1(int id) {
    while (!stopThread) {
        bool err = false;
        for (size_t i = 0; !stopThread && i < v.size(); i++) {
            if (id == v[i] - > id) {
                c.   out << "element found " << v[i] - > id << " -- " << v[i] - > name << endl;
                v[i] - > Read();
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
                err = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, here's what I did... First, I set up so your thread lasts, which I think is what you want. I gave you a means of telling the thread to stop (the stopThread variable). And your thread now loops until you tell it to quit.

This isn't *exactly* how I would write it, but it's close to what I'd do while making minimal changes to your code.

Comment: I am done with the before problem..now I have to implement simultaneous running of threads.when I start to monitor an ID and simultaneously pressed start monitor option again,I should be able to monitor both.

Comment: ``int id; cout << "ID to be monitored" << endl;; cin >> id;
                if (myThread!=0) 
                    {
                        stopThread = true; 
                        
                        myThread->join();
                        
                        delete myThread; 
                    }
                    
                stopThread = false; 
                vec.push_back(thread(thred1,id));
                myThread!=0;
                break;```  it works but I cannot stop this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but I am posting this because correct multi-threaded coding is non-trivial and I wanted to highlight a number of things you may want to consider.

Here is my solution to what I interpret as your problem.

There are a few points of (I hope) interest:

1. Thread is encapsulated in the component
2. component implementation, lifetime and handle objects are factored out on the principle of 1-class-1-job
3. inter-thread sequencing is taken account of when controlling component activity
4. mutex around the use of `std::cout` controlled via the `emit()` function template.
5. clean shutdown

Code offered as-is. Tested on MacOS. There will be bugs. There always are in the first cut of multi-threaded code.

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  so-58625693
//

#include <ciso646>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex emit_mutex;

template<class...Ts>
void emit(Ts&&...ts)
{
    auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(emit_mutex);
    int x[] = {
        0,
        (std::cout << ts, 0)...
    };
    (void) x;
}

// implements the workings of a component
class component_impl : public std::enable_shared_from_this<component_impl>
{
    using mutex_type = std::mutex;
    using lock_type = std::unique_lock<mutex_type>;

    enum state_type
    {
        stopped,
        started,
        stopping
    };

    template<class F>
    auto sync(F f) const
    {
        return f(lock_type(mutex_));
    }

public:

    component_impl(int type, int id, std::string name)
    : type_(type), id_(id), name_(std::move(name))
    {}

    auto start() -> void
    {
        sync([&](auto&& lock){
            switch(state_)
            {
                case stopped:
                    handle_start(lock);
                    break;

                case started:
                case stopping:
                    emit(identity(), " is already started\n");
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    bool stop() {
        auto did_stop = sync([&](auto&& lock){
            switch(state_)
            {
                case stopping:
                case stopped:
                    return false;

                case started:
                    state_ = stopping;
                    stop_condition_.notify_one();
                    emit(identity(), " stop requested\n");
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

        if (did_stop and thread_.joinable())
            thread_.join();

        return did_stop;
    }

    void display() const
    {
        identify(std::cout);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    void identify(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        os << type_ << " : " << id_ << " : " << name_;
    }

    auto identity() const -> std::string
    {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        identify(ss);
        return ss.str();
    }

    auto id() const -> int {
        return id_;
    }

private:

    auto run() -> void
    {
        using namespace std::literals;

        auto lock = lock_type(mutex_);
        for(;;)
        {
            auto stop = stop_condition_.wait_for(lock, 2s, [&] { return state_ != started; });
            if (stop)
            {
                state_ = stopped;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                lock.unlock();
                emit(identity(), " sampling\n");
                lock.lock();
            }
        }
    }

    // precondition: mutex is locked
    // precondition: not started
    auto handle_start(lock_type const& lock) -> void
    {
        assert(lock.owns_lock());
        assert(state_ == stopped);

        thread_ = std::thread([self = this->shared_from_this()]
        {
            self->run();
        });

        state_ = started;
    }


    // invariants

    const int type_, id_;
    const std::string name_;

    // control
    mutable mutex_type mutex_;
    std::condition_variable stop_condition_;
    std::thread thread_;

    // mutable state
    state_type state_ = stopped;
};

struct component_lifetime
{
    component_lifetime(std::unique_ptr<component_impl> impl)
    : impl_(std::move(impl))
    {
    }

    ~component_lifetime()
    {
        impl_->stop();
    }

    auto impl() -> component_impl&
    {
        return *impl_;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<component_impl> impl_;
};

// manages the lifetime of a component
struct component
{
    component(int type, int id, std::string name)
    : impl_(construct_lifetime(type, id, std::move(name)))
    {
    }

    component_lifetime& lifetime() { return *impl_; }
    component_lifetime& lifetime() const { return *impl_; }

    component_impl& impl() { return lifetime().impl(); }
    component_impl& impl() const { return lifetime().impl(); }


    void start()
    {
        impl().start();
    }


    int id() const {
        return impl().id();
    }

    void display() const
    {
        impl().display();
    }

    bool stop()
    {
        return impl().stop();
    }


private:

    static auto construct_impl(int type, int id, std::string name) -> std::unique_ptr<component_impl>
    {
        return std::make_unique<component_impl>(type, id, std::move(name));
    }

    static auto construct_lifetime(int type, int id, std::string name) -> std::shared_ptr<component_lifetime>
    {
        auto impl = construct_impl(type, id, std::move(name));
        auto lifetime = std::make_shared<component_lifetime>(std::move(impl));
        return lifetime;
    }


    std::shared_ptr<component_lifetime> impl_;
};


struct component_set
{
    component_set() = default;
    component_set(component_set const&) = delete;
    component_set& operator=(component_set const&) = delete;
    ~component_set()
    {
        shutdown();
    }

    void add(int type, int id, std::string name) {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_);
        v_.emplace_back(type, id, std::move(name));
    }

    auto locate(int id) -> component*
    {
        auto match_id = [id](component const& c)
        {
            return c.id() == id;
        };

        auto i = std::find_if(std::begin(v_), std::end(v_), match_id);

        if (i != std::end(v_))
            return std::addressof(*i);
        else
            return nullptr;
    }

    void start(int id)
    {
        auto pc = locate(id);
        if (pc)
            pc->start();
        else
            emit("id ", id, " not found\n");
    }

    void stop(int id)
    {
        auto pc = locate(id);
        if (pc)
        {
            if (not pc->stop())
            {
                emit("id ", id, " was not running");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            emit("id ", id, " not found\n");
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_);
        for (auto&& c : v_)
        {
            c.display();
        }
    }

    auto shutdown() -> void
    {
        for (auto&& c : v_)
            c.stop();
    }

private:
    std::mutex m_;
    std::vector < component > v_;
};

int main() {
    int choose;
    int type;
    int id;
    std::string name;
    component_set components;

    do {
        emit("1.ADD A COMPONENT\n"
             "2.DISPLAY A COMPONENT\n"
             "3.START MONITORING\n"
             "4.STOP MONITORING\n"
             "5.QUIT\n");
        std::cin >> choose;
        switch (choose) {
        case 1:
            emit("enter type, id and name:\n");
            std::cin >> type >> id >> name;
            components.add(type, id, name);
            // fall through
        case 2:
            components.display();
            break;

        case 3:
            emit("ID to be monitored\n");
            std::cin >> id;
            components.start(id);
            break;

        case 4:
            emit("ID to be stopped\n");
            std::cin >> id;
            components.stop(id);
            break;
        }
    } while (choose != 5);
}
```